# Openshift application and ejb "failed deployments ./ROOT.war

Tags: jpa, jboss, ejb, openshift

I'm developing a first application on openshift. Its a jsf application with database connectitivity.
First i tryed onli some jsf xhtml page without jpa and all  works.
When i insert a bean to acces to the database i have the message from the server "failed  deployments ./ROOT.waer. Precisely when I insert this code something goes wrong :

A class for view intents

```
 @ManagedBean(name="utnavctrl" ,eager=true)
@SessionScoped
public class Utnavctrl {
    boolean newrecord=false;
    @EJB
    private Usersdao usersdao;
public Utnavctrl(){
```

A bean class for db connection

```
    @Stateless
@LocalBean
public class Usersdao {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Usersdao() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
                return em.createNamedQuery("User.findAll", User.class)
                    .getResultList();
            }
```

I can't understand why after adding these two class (without modifing the view side xhtml ecc)  the program doesn't work anymore.

The persince.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="primary">
      <!-- If you are running in a production environment, add a managed 
         data source, this example data source is just for development and testing! -->
      <!-- The datasource is deployed as WEB-INF/kitchensink-quickstart-ds.xml, you
         can find it in the source at src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/kitchensink-quickstart-ds.xml -->
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
      <class>com.antoiovi.gestcars.model.Automobili</class>
      <class>com.antoiovi.gestcars.model.Group</class>
      <class>com.antoiovi.gestcars.model.Prenotazioniauto</class>
      <class>com.antoiovi.gestcars.model.Proglav</class>
      <class>com.antoiovi.gestcars.model.Role</class>
      <class>com.antoiovi.gestcars.model.User</class>
      <class>com.antoiovi.gestcars.model.UserData</class>

      <properties>
         <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Thhe bean.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This file can be an empty text file (0 bytes) -->
<!-- We're declaring the schema to save you time if you do have to configure 
   this in the future -->
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</bean
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Remove eager=true because this creates problems with OpenShift...I do not know why but I have seen.